# Why is my ui not updating?

Tags: jquery, debugging, knockout.js, data-binding, jsfiddle

When I try to [add items](https://jsfiddle.net/WouterVos/9hc36310/12/) for user input:

```
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.concentration = ko.observable();
    self.calibrations = ko.observableArray();
    self.sampleMeasure = ko.observable();

    self.add = function() {
    debugger;
        self.calibrations.push({
            x: undefined,
            yT: undefined,
            yM: undefined
        });
    };

    self.remove = function() {
        self.calibrations.remove(this);
    };

    self.testing = function() {
        var data = [
            { x: 2, yT: 5.5, yM: 5.3 },
            { x: 6, yT: 13.5, yM: 13.2 },
            { x: 8, yT: 17.5, yM: 17.2 },
            { x: 10, yT: 21.5, yM: 21.6 },
            { x: 14, yT: 29.5, yM: 29.3 },
            { x: 19, yT: 39.5, yM: 39.6 }
        ];

        ko.utils.arrayPushAll(data, self.calibrations);

        self.calculateSampleConcentration();
    };

    self.calculateSampleConcentration = function() {
    debugger;
        self.concentration = 5;
    };

    self.testing();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

I've tried to add `debugger;` statements for to see what's happening, but it doesn't show the source code breaking there, although it show the processor has stopped.

It also keep showing the following error:

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

Even though I removed the form element surrounding my inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not [binding click events](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) properly:

It should be:

```
<button data-bind="click: add">Add Calibration</button>
```

The `remove` button should also be changed to:

```
<button data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove</button>
```

The remove function still won't work. It should be changed to:

```
self.remove = function(item) {
   // "item" argument will have the current calibration item being removed
   self.calibrations.remove(item);
};
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/9hc36310/10/). You'll need change other buttons along the same lines.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can debug the code? Never mind my previous (now deleted) question, that was due to parameter order, apologies.

Comment: @MrFox you can add `debugger;` inside the functions. But you'd have to keep the dev tools open in jsfiddle (By pressing F12). It wasn't working for you because the function ws never called because of the syntax error.